# Sharepoint Designer Workflow when item is published

Tags: designer-workflow, publishing-page

I see that Designer has the option to see the approval status of an item, however how can i see if an item is published or not... I have a wiki page library and i want to run some logic when the user publishes a page.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I am assuming you have versioning turned on, if so, what Document Versioning History setting are you using?  Also, what kind of logic are looking to do--Workflows, javascript, .NET, etc?  If you could elaborate, it would be helpful!

Comment: I do have versioning enabled tracking drafts and major publishes. I did find that the following code, but have not tested all possibile scenarios for unwanted results:
            int beforeLevel = (int)properties.BeforeProperties["vti_level"];
            int afterLevel = (int)properties.AfterProperties["vti_level"];
            bool isPublished = false;

            if (((beforeLevel == 255) || (afterLevel == 1)) || (beforeLevel == afterLevel && beforeLevel == 2))
            {
                isPublished = true;
            }
            return isPublished;